# Confused about the "-a" switch of netstat on mac os

Tags: osx, netstat

The `-a` switch [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html) says the following:

> **-a**    With the default display, show the state of all sockets; **normally sockets used by server processes**
>         **are not shown**. With the routing table display (option -r, as described below), show protocol-cloned
>         routes (routes generated by a RTF_PRCLONING parent route); normally these routes are
>         not shown.

What is meant by "server processes", is it processes that use server/listening sockets?

Comment: "Server processes" in this context means processes [`listening`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/listen.2.html) on a socket, that is, waiting for connections. Without this switch, `netstat` shows only connected sockets.

Answer (score 0):

The flag simply allows the user to look at all processes/sockets used. If not supplied with -a, then the user will not see the state of EVERYTHING on the system.

To put it nicely, it just means "all"